# Which flags should I use with htmlspecialchars?

Tags: php, html, security, escaping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do the ENT_HTML5, ENT_HTML401, … modifiers on html_entity_decode do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745353/what-do-the-ent-html5-ent-html401-modifiers-on-html-entity-decode-do)

When using htmlspecialchars to escape output that goes to an html attribute, I am wondering what flag is correct.

it seems that `ENT_QUOTES` would be safer than `ENT_COMPAT` because it cannot fail if someone accidently adds some code with single quoted attributes, but so why does `ENT_COMPAT` exist? Is there a disadvantage to  `ENT_QUOTES`?

Also what are the security implications of using `ENT_HTML5`, `ENT_XHTML` or `ENT_HTML401` or not setting one at all?

Comment: Similar questions were asked here very often, I suppose. ) So instead of an answer I'll just suggest reading [this article](http://blog.astrumfutura.com/2012/03/a-hitchhikers-guide-to-cross-site-scripting-xss-in-php-part-1-how-not-to-use-htmlspecialchars-for-output-escaping/). )

Comment: Thanks alot. I'm sorry if I missed the duplicates. I did search. The article is hard to read (it's like a pot of worms), but it (and the rest of that blog) definitely is the most useful resource I have found sofar. However claims like 'you can ignore the existence of these flags' without any justification are problematic.